# creating sessions and validation of data in php

Tags: php, mysql

I created a PHP script for retrieving data from a table and storing data upon selection in another table by submitting the form. I have trouble in creating sessions for storing values and validation of data. How can I create a session and validate the data upon selection of the items in drop down.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "leave-form";

$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;
dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {

    try {

        $sql = "INSERT INTO authority (emp_name, repo_auth, contr_auth)
VALUES   ('" . $_POST["emp_name"] . "','" . $_POST["repo_auth"] . "','" . $_POST["contr_auth"] . "')";
        if ($dbh->query($sql)) {
            echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('New Record Inserted   Successfully');</script>";
        } else {
            echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('Data not successfully   Inserted.');</script>";
        }
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
?>

<div class="container">
    <h1>Admin</h1>
    <form name="registration" action="" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Employee name:</td>
                <td>
                    <select name="emp_name">
                        <option value=""> -----------Select----------- </option> 
                        <?php
                        $stmt = $dbh->prepare('Select name from people');
                        $stmt->execute();
                        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                            echo '<option>' . $row['name'] . '</option>';
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select> 
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Manager:</td>
                <td>
                    <select name="repo_auth">
                        <option value=""> -----------Select----------- </option> 
                        <?php
                        $stmt = $dbh->prepare('Select name from people');
                        $stmt->execute();
                        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                            echo '<option>' . $row['name'] . '</option>';
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select> 
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Senior Manager:</td>
                <td>
                    <select name="contr_auth">
                        <option value=""> -----------Select----------- </option> 
                        <?php
                        $stmt = $dbh->prepare('Select name from people');
                        $stmt->execute();
                        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                            echo '<option>' . $row['name'] . '</option>';
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select> 
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" />
                    <input type="reset" name="cancel" value="clear"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't find any session or validation related code. What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: since i am a newbie i do not know how to add a session or validate the code if a duplicate user is found

Comment: **WARNING**: When using PDO you should be using prepared statements and supply any user data as separate arguments because you have severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) in this code. Never use string interpolation or concatenation and instead use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). Refer to [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) for guidance with this and other problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this way :

### SESSIONS :

Sessions are most important & a very easy main element of PHP.You can use Session to store values in it and then you can access those values across other pages of your PHP Script.Unllke **COOKIES** Sessions are alot secure than Cookies as Cookies are saved on client side and can be manipulated which can cause more harm than anything else while on the other sie Sessions are server side.You may store some value in a Session but the actual Session is stored on the server.You can't manipulate it so that's why it's more secure to use Sessions instead of Cookies but both have their roles in use of each other at certain places in your code.!

**How To Create A Session :**

Creating a Session is very easy,
A session can be created like this way :

```
$_SESSION['session_name'] = $value;
```

2nd you can now access your session in your other PHP script pages like this way:

```
$stored_value = $_SESSION['session_name'];
echo $stored_value;
```

Note : Remember to run the `session_start()` statement on both these pages before you try to access the `$_SESSION` array, and also before any output is sent to the browser.Simply add `session_start()` at the full begining of your each and every page in which you are going to use Session either for setting a Session or if trying to retrieve one.!

### SIMPLE USE OF SESSION :

**Scenario :**
For Instance I want to create a Session upon logging in and then to be able to visit other pages with the established Session until the session is destroyed.!
So Here is exactly how can I do it :

**On Login Page (index.php or login.php) :**

```
<?php
session_start(); 
// Add session_start() just right after the PHP Starting Tags 
// Or you will be getting Header Sent Already Error

if ($db_username == $input_username && $db_password == $input_password) {
    $_SESSION['user'] = $db_username;
    header("Location : home.php");
} else {
    echo "Username & Password Is Wrong";
}
?>
```

And now on your `home.php` you can access the data which can be only accessed if session is there like this way :

**On Home Page (home.php) :**

```
<?php
session_start();
$user =  $_SESSION['user'];
if (isset($user)) {
    echo "Welcome User : ".$user;
} else {
    // If Session is not there you will be redirected back to login page.!
    header("Location: login.php");
}
?>
```

And now if you want to logout so you can destroy session like this way by just visiting the `logout.php` page :

**Logout Page (logout.php) :**

```
<?php
session_start();
if (session_destroy()) {
    header("Location: login.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: how to add the session to my script since i am a beginner

Comment: now i want to create session for each field for example if a user selects an item from each dropdown but the user has forgot to select an item from another dropdown so the user has to be reminded to fill/select only that field since the rest items are stored using session and each field should have a unique name i.e i can have my reporting manager and senior manager as same and my firend can have it too but same names i.e., all the selected dropdown have same values it has to be validated and a msg should pop like all the fields cannot be same

Comment: I know you're trying to help here, but what you're recommending is incomplete and doesn't follow best practices. Any [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) already has a structure for handling this, like how [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) has a robust and complete [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication) built-in. There's no need to go and re-invent the wheel here.

Comment: @tadman : Are you blind?? Just want to know that you can't see the he doesn't even know how to create and add a session and you are talking about laraval...!

Comment: Larvel is extremely well documented and approaches all this stuff in a very standard, organized way. What you're advocating here fell out of fashion in the 1990s, it's total chaos and it is full of holes. Laravel provides a very clear path to doing this correctly, and any framework worth using does the same. The last thing a person new to PHP needs to be subjected to start with the lowest level functions and build up from nothing and fumbling along while trying to do basic things. Frameworks are **essential** to being productive.

Comment: @tadman Your comments solutions & downvoting doesn't concern this question at all..! I don't know that why would you be doing this then?? At least I didn't expect this much hate from a seniour member instead of encouraging the young members..!

Comment: Let's call this tough love. The PHP community seems indifferent to people rolling their own horrendously bad login systems, some so terribly broken they do the opposite, they let people hack your server at will. Ruby has Rails, Python has Django, Node.js has Express, all of which are the first thing people use when solving problems like this. PHP has *several* frameworks, all of which are great, and yet people like you refuse to even consider using them and scare people away from even trying. Programming is hard enough with out having to start from the very bottom.

Comment: @tadman : I am very keen & looking forward myself to learning Laraval soon enough.I already heard about it from an another friend just a little while ago he really praised it very much.Just to be honest I can see that how popular it is becoming as I see most of the questions about laraval..! Besides Thanks..!

Comment: I don't advertise PHP because I use other tools to solve my problems, but I want to help lift the standards and expectations for people in the PHP world by sharing what I've learned from other communities: **Frameworks make people better programmers** and **having conventions makes things easier**. Your renegade approach here might solve an immediate problem but it comes at a price. Learning a framework solves many problems and gives you access to a huge number of modules that can add very powerful features to your app with very little effort.

Comment: @tadman : Thank you so much for clarifying your point.And please accept my sincere apology for being rude..!

Comment: I don't mind. Unfortunately I expect a lot of hostility from people when bringing this up, even when it should be taken for granted. PHP is unique and very lucky to have several very well maintained, full-featured frameworks and a huge library of packages in [Composer](https://getcomposer.org) and [PEAR](https://pear.php.net). It's a huge dis-service to the people that spent time writing and documenting those to ignore them, and a waste of your time to re-do what they've already done. I think you'll like Laravel, and if you don't, you have many others to choose from. Good luck!

Comment: @tadman Would it be possible to get your Skype ID or how to get in a chat here somwhere with you???